# Short Circuit Model Validation C#

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .NET Core 2.0.
I have a POST action on my controller. It binds the data from the body of the request (JSON) into a C# DTO. On the DTO I have validation attributes - for instance:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(512)]
public string email { get; set; }
```

These validators execute in the order that they are defined on the property.

I would like to short-circuit the validation if a prior validator fails. For example - if the required validation fails, don't execute the max length validation.

Is there a way to override the default model validation behavior to continue to the next property if one of the validators fails?

Comment: Attribute order is not necessarily preserved upon compilation so your idea would not work.  You could create your own attribute that does whatever logic you want

Comment: I suggest you to use  [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-ASP.NET-MVC-5-integration)

Comment: I appreciate the responses. I'll check out FluentValidation - looks like a nice way to keep the model clean.

Comment: @Hamix, I ended up using FluentValidation for this. Very helpful - thank you.

Comment: @Daryl Good luck ;p