# Is there a way to short-circut data annotation based model validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

Is there a way to tell ASP.NET MVC:

1. *Not* to go ahead with validating the rest of the validation attributes if a certain one of them fails?
2. And then also, to go ahead with the rest of the validation attributes regardless of whether or not a specific one fails? This seems to be the default behavior anyway.

For e.g.

```
[MaxLength(200)] // don't go ahead with the next 
                 // validation attribute applied, i.e. the
                 // RegularExpressionAttribute below if this one 
                 // fails, since there really would be no point in 
                 // doing that.
[RegularExpression(...)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And then also sometimes to configure it the other way, i.e. to not tell is to short-circut, which seems to be the default behavior currently, like so:

```
[MaxLength(200)]  // sure, go ahead with the next one 
                  // even if this one fails
[RegularExpression(...)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Basically, my question is almost the same as [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48937926/303685).

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 targeting .NET framework 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I don't believe MVC offers this functionality with their provided data annotations.

You should ask yourself why you'd want to follow your proposed approach. The type of validations performed by MVC data annotations are computationally simple, there's no point in *existing on first failure*. If your annotations are decorating a view model, the user will almost certainly prefer to see everything that failed, so they can rectify all their mistakes in one go. Resubmitting a form only to find a subsequent field fails validation would be a nightmare.